# If jquery cdn fails Load from local

Tags: jquery, html

its loading from local  but its loading both from local and cdn in this condition

```
> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
>  <script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery1.5.1.min.js"></script>')

</script>
```

I have to load from local only if cdn fails

Comment: `<scriptsrc=` is missing a space.

Comment: ok but thats not the issue

Comment: you may need to wait for jquery  to be loaded from cdn

Comment: you can't use `src` and put something inside the script element at the same time + you need to escape the `</script>` to `<\/script>` so that the html parser will not close the script element.

Comment: this will solve loading  jquery from both cdn and local ?